# Matplotlib animation is not saved correctly

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I produced an animation of a contour field with pyplot and would like to save it as movie file. Unfortunately, when I save it I get a file of the right format and I can open it with, say, VLC, but it contains just one or two frames.

This a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# Initialize figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Initialize mesh
x = np.r_[-5:5:100j]
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)

# Computes the data and yields them
def data_generator(X, Y, dt):
    for t in np.r_[:10:dt]:
        yield t, np.tanh(Y*(2+t)) + np.sqrt(np.abs(X))

# Plots the given solution on the given axes
def plotter(data, ax, X, Y):
    ax.clear()
    t, field = data
    C = ax.contour(X, Y, field)
    ax.set_title('Time: {0:.1f}'.format(t))
    return C

# Animation object
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, plotter, frames=data_generator(X, Y, 0.1),
                     interval=100, repeat=False, fargs=(ax,X,Y))
anim.save('animation.mp4')
plt.show()
```

I'm using `python-3.5.0` on Arch linux, with `matplotlib-1.5.0`. I have `ffmpeg-2.8.2` installed. I tried with different formats (e.g. `avi`, `mkv`, `mov`), and I also tried with explicitly selecting the `ffmpeg` and `ffmpeg_file` writers. The problem is not with my hard disk running out of space. What else should I check?

Comment: Did running the script with `--debug-verbose` give any clues?

Comment: I just did it and I got no message at all.

Comment: This is a know bug :( It will be fixed in 1.5.1.  The work around is to pass in a `init_func`

Comment: Thanks, tcaswell. I fixed my script by passing a trivial function to the constructor: `init_func = lambda : None`.